# How to get values of selected dropdown box and insert to database?

Tags: php, mysql

I just created a quantity drop down box, the only thing is when add cart button is clicked, the quantity or the selected value of dropdown box is not inserting to table name cart with column qty please help.. below is code from functions.php and product.php

```
<div id="products_box">
        <?php

 $get_pro = "select * from products ";
 $run_pro = mysqli_query($con, $get_pro);
 while($row_pro=mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro)){
    $pro_id = $row_pro['product_id'];
    $pro_cat = $row_pro['product_cat'];
    $pro_brand = $row_pro['product_brand'];
    $pro_title = $row_pro['product_title'];
    $pro_price = $row_pro['product_price'];
    $pro_image = $row_pro['product_image'];
    $pro_qty = $row_pro['product_qty'];
    echo "
        <div id='single_product'>
        <h4>$pro_title</h4>
        <img src='admin_area/product_images/$pro_image' width='180' height='80' />
        <p><b> Php $pro_price.00</b></p>
        <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id' style='float:left;'>Details</a>
        <select name='quantity'>";
        for($i=1;$i<=$pro_qty;$i++) {
         echo  "<option value=$i>$i</option>";
          }
        echo  "</select>

        <a href='index.php'?pro_id=$pro_id'><button style='float:right'>Add to Cart</button></a>
        </div>
        ";

}
?>
        </div>


function cart(){
if(isset($_GET['add_cart'])){
    global $con;
    $ip = getIp();
    $pro_id = $_GET['add_cart'];
    $pro_qty = $_POST['quantity'];
    $check_pro = "select * from cart where ip_add='$ip' AND p_id='$pro_id'";
    $run_check = mysqli_query($con, $check_pro);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($run_check)>0){
        echo ""; //refresh or do nothing
    }
    else {
    $insert_pro = "insert into cart(p_id,ip_add,qty) values ('$pro_id','$ip','$pro_qty')";
    $run_pro = mysqli_query($con, $insert_pro);
    echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
    }
```

}
}

Comment: can you plz try this  echo  "<option value=$i>$i</option>"; replace it to echo  "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";

Comment: the values are displaying on drop box, the problem is getting the selected value..

Comment: <a href='index.php?pro_id=$pro_id'>

Comment: @ReniDelaCruzCalonge See you are not using a sumbit button to pass your form values, you are using href it will not carry form values,

Comment: Did the loop content belong to on form ? for your case if you want get the data from request on the server side , here is three method 1.via form(post/get) 2.via href way 3.via ajax way. so please tell me which way did you used ? i don't know why you used $_GET and $_POST at the same time on you server side.@ReniDelaCruzCalonge

Comment: there's two php form.. it includes the function.php or should i remove it from function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please give a try to this

```
<div id="products_box">
        <?php

 $get_pro = "select * from products ";
 $run_pro = mysqli_query($con, $get_pro);
 while($row_pro=mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro)){
    $pro_id = $row_pro['product_id'];
    $pro_cat = $row_pro['product_cat'];
    $pro_brand = $row_pro['product_brand'];
    $pro_title = $row_pro['product_title'];
    $pro_price = $row_pro['product_price'];
    $pro_image = $row_pro['product_image'];
    $pro_qty = $row_pro['product_qty'];
    echo "
        <form method='post' action='index.php'>
        <input type='hidden' value= '".$pro_id."' name ='pro_id' />
        <div id='single_product'>
        <h4>$pro_title</h4>
        <img src='admin_area/product_images/$pro_image' width='180' height='80' />
        <p><b> Php $pro_price.00</b></p>
        <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id' style='float:left;'>Details</a>
        <select name='quantity'>";
        for($i=1;$i<=$pro_qty;$i++) {
         echo  "<option value=$i>$i</option>";
          }
        echo  "</select>

        <input type='submit' name='add' value='Add to Cart'>
        </div>
        </form>
        ";

}
?>
        </div>


function cart(){
if(isset($_GET['add_cart'])){
    global $con;
    $ip = getIp();
    $pro_id = $_POST['pro_id'];
    $pro_qty = $_POST['quantity'];
    $check_pro = "select * from cart where ip_add='$ip' AND p_id='$pro_id'";
    $run_check = mysqli_query($con, $check_pro);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($run_check)>0){
        echo ""; //refresh or do nothing
    }
    else {
    $insert_pro = "insert into cart(p_id,ip_add,qty) values ('$pro_id','$ip','$pro_qty')";
    $run_pro = mysqli_query($con, $insert_pro);
    echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: i now have two buttons

Comment: nothing happened, none was inserted.. 
i tried this. <a href='index.php?add_cart=$pro_id'>  instead of a href='index.php'?pro_id=$pro_id', records was inserted but qty gets a value of 0

Comment: in previous case you are not submitting form, you were redirecting the form. Answer which i was posted working fine on my side. Have you tried with print input values on index.php or not?

Comment: btw should i change if(isset($_GET['add_cart'])){ to POST?

Comment: please remove  if(isset($_GET['add_cart'])) judgement based on @bablu code and test it again .